# Use PHP `variables value` quickly in HTML

Tags: php, html, variables

I often use HTML template for my application and within the template content there are `place holder` which I marked as `<?php echo $myVar; ?>`

Is there a shorter syntax for that? I tried `<?php=$myVar?>` but didn't work :D

Please give a hint if you know some way. Thank you!

```
<body>
    <?php $myVar = 122; ?>
    abb
    <div>
        <?php echo $myVar; ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php=$myVar?>
    </div>
    ccc
</body>
```

Comment: It was `<?= $myval ?>`. I think this will be deprecated from version PHP v6.0, so keep it in mind for future.

Comment: For cleaner templates i would suggest a templating engine. For example, look at [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/syntax_comparison)

Comment: @Rolice <?= is now always available regardless of the short_tags setting in php5.4 alpha

Comment: I don't see a problem with <?php echo $myVar; ?>
I use it all the time and it's easy to spot in your template.

Comment: Yes I agree, but it should be kept in mind, to avoid potential surprises when the final version of PHP 6.0 is released, for now it is just a rumor.

Comment: @Veinbergs Would love to hear why need a template engine from you. Please tell me more.

Comment: @Rolice its not a rumor its implemented. Just as RiaD said short_tags will always be on from php5.4

Comment: @spankmaster79 I don't said that short_tags will be on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?=$myvar ?>
```

short_open_tag should be On.

Comment: +1 for the note about `short_open_tag`. Note that since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available.

Answer (score 3):

The shorter version is `<?=$myVar;?>`, but please DON'T do this! :(

Quoting from the comment, in case anyone misses it.

> because:
>
> 1. This will not allow much flexibility in moving the servers, i.e. you must control the server or be allowed to change the ini 
>      directives [to turn on short_open_tag], otherwise you are doomed.
> 2. It might be deprecated in the future.
> 3. Readability is not a trade for functionality. Period.

Comment: Why not to do it? In PHP 5.4... it will be enabled by default.

Comment: Because this requires short_open_tag be enabled, which can conflict with
xml.

Comment: why not? Do you really want to see a lot of echos?

Comment: Well it does. You can't just cancel the opening tag of xml :/ But still if Eddie never uses xml in this document he doesn't have to worry about it.

Comment: @RiaD: YES, I would love to see lots/tons of echos, because: 1) This will not allow much flexibility in moving the servers, i.e. you must control the server or be allowed to change the ini directives, otherwise you are doomed. 2) It might be deprecated in the future. 3) Readability is not a trade for functionality. Period.

Answer (score 3):

You can use short tags if enabled.

```
<?= $var; ?>
```

This is the same as doing this:

```
<?php echo $var; ?>
```

To set this up you can find info here, however it's not recommended you use this method.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

If ASP tags are enabled you can also do things like this:

```
<%=$var; %>

<% echo $var; $>
```

Answer (score 2):

it is

```
<?=$myVar; ?>
```

short tag should be enabled with PHP

If you are going to use inline xml with PHP do not enable short tags.

As documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

> If you want to use PHP in combination with XML, you can disable this
>   option in order to use  inline. Otherwise, you can print it
>   with PHP, for example: '; ?>. Also,
>   if disabled, you must use the long form of the PHP open tag ().

Answer (score 0):

You could use double quote echo like this:

```
<?php
$myVar = 122;
echo "
<body>
    abb
    <div>
         whatever and $myVar displayed here
    </div>
    <div>
        The content is: $myOtherVar
    </div>
    sometext
</body>
";
?>
```

But consider using your template with OOP. It would be even cleaner:

```
Template::header();//Echoes your template header

Template::content($myContentText,$myWhateverVar);//Echoes your template filled with your vars
```

HTH,
caffein